# Host MVC Application in AppHarbour

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, appharbor

I've hosted MVC application having MySql server instance in AppHarbour as backend but build is getting failed. We would like to connect MySql instance from local application but it can't access tables and schema while is opening and connecting to instance successfully.

Answer (score 3):

You can't connect AppHarbor to a local db. If you have a hosted MySql instance though, you can connect it to that.

AppHarbor shows you build errors. You can read the build output and find out why it is failing (if it is the build failing or unit tests failing).

Either way, whether or not MySql is hosted or local, that shouldn't affect whether or not the project builds in AppHarbor.